# How can i fix snap warnings for brave?

Tags: snap, brave

How can i fix snap warning for brave ?

platform :
Linux 5.15.0-79-generic #86~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 17 23:27:17 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

> sudo snap list

> > brave     1.57.53     268    latest/stable  brave✓  -

after last

> sudo snap refresh

a get a warning

> > sudo snap warnings
> > last-occurrence:  Il y a 3 jours, à 18 h 59 HNR (in english 3 days ago)
> > warning: |
> > snap "brave" has bad plugs or slots: content (content plug must contain target path)

i see same problem here
https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/32506

Comment: seems new snap refresh fix warning thx

Answer (score 0):

Rerun snap refresh. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap refresh
```